# whats the difference between these 2 very similar haskell State computations

Tags: haskell, state

I am trying to learn the haskell State monad. So I wrote a function to generate a list of random numbers using the State monad.

Here is the first version.

```
rnds :: Int -> [Int]
rnds n = evalState (help (mkStdGen 007)) []
  where help prng = do s <- get
            let (a, nprng) = randomR (1,6) prng                                 
            put (a:s)
            if length s == n then (return s)
                             else (help nprng)
```

Here is the second version.

```
rnds1 :: Int -> [Int]
rnds1 n = evalState (help (mkStdGen 007)) []
  where help prng = do s <- get
            let (a, nprng) = randomR (1,6) prng                                 
            put (a:s)
            ns <- get
            if length ns == n then (return ns)
                              else (help nprng)
```

For the same parameters they both give the same output. But in the first version, to check the length of the list (which is the state by the way) I am referencing the list `s`. But `s` was obtained before I did `put (a:s)`. So when I'm checking the length, I assumed it would give the length of 's' before I did `put (a:s)`. But it doesn't seem so because the output of the first version is the same as the second one if both are given the same parameters.

The second version is easier to understand atleast for me. Before I check the length of the list `ns`, I first do `ns <- get` to get the new updated state.

Can someone please tell me what's going on? I get the feeling I gravely misunderstood something about the way Haskell works or something about the State monad itself.

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: Expand out the do-notaion, the definition of >>= for State, and the definition of get and put... http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/1.1.0.2/doc/html/src/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html#State

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `rnds`,

```
put (a:s)
if length s == n then (return s)
```

you return the list you obtained from the `get`, and not the one you `put` into the state, so you're producing one pseudo-random number more than in `rnds1` (which you then ignore), but return the same list.

Answer (score 4):

As Daniel pointed out, I think this is just a coincidence due to the algorithm you used. If you use a simpler program its easier to see that values don't "magically" get mutated after you extract them from the hidden state:

```
module Main where
import Control.Monad.State

test = evalState comp 1
  where
    comp = do
     x <- get
     put 2
     y <- get
     return (x,y)

main = do
   print test
```

This program prints out (1,2), showing that once you get the `x` clearly has the "old" value even after you do a "put".